# Replace double quotes with single quotes in json string in php

Tags: php, json, preg-replace

I have a json string which contains some html and it's attrubutes. I'm trying to to escape or replace double quotes with single quotes in this string. my code works with some html attributes but not with all.
My example:

```
$json='{"en":"<b class="test" size="5" >Description</b>"}';
$json=preg_replace('/([^:,{])"([^:,}])/', "$1".'\''."$2",$json);
echo htmlspecialchars($json);
//ouput: {"en":"<b class='test' size='5" >Description</b>"}
```

Needed result:

```
{"en":"<b class='test' size='5' >Description</b>"}
```

Comment: Interesting problem. Did you try https://regex101.com/ ?

Comment: That's not a JSON string in your example. What created such a strange string? Can you fix it to give you real JSON (with " properly escaped) instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope this works as expected `([^{,:])"(?![},:])`

```
$json='{"en":"<b class="test" size="5" >Description</b>"}';
$json=preg_replace('/([^{,:])"(?![},:])/', "$1".'\''."$2",$json);
```

Results in

```
{"en":"<b class='test' size='5' >Description</b>"}
```

Comment: Nice solution. We should add that in the example string the problem with the last quotation mark is, that the character infront of it is already consumed by the previous match. Your solution used a "negative lookahead" instead. That doesn't consume characters. Problem solved.

Comment: Altough you code works for most of the typical cases, if you have quotes and commas inside the json value the closing quotes won't be escaped, ex: `{"en":"grass and "flowers", "sky""}` it will become: `{"en":"grass and \"flowers", \"sky\""}`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Please give me the correct way to handle your case and I'll test and update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one : `str_replace('"', "'",$json);`

```
$json='{"en":"<b class="test" size="5" >Description</b>"}';
$json=str_replace('"', "'",$json);
echo htmlspecialchars($json);
```

Output will : `{'en':'<b class='test' size='5' >Description</b>'}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The value of json must still have double quotes.